# multer single upload doesnot work but array works

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, multer

I am using react js to upload a single file. But multer.single() doesnot work whereas multer.array() works. What's the problem?

```
//Node.js
const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        destination: './uploads',
        filename: (_, file, cb) => cb(null, file.originalname),
    }),
});
// app.use(upload.array('pdf')); // works
app.use(upload.single('pdf')); // not working
```

The error when using single method is

```
(node:6096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at convertToJPG (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\controllers\convert.js:9:44)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:6096) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Client side code is

```
<input
          accept=".pdf"
          multiple={false}
          name="pdf"
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
          ref={fileInputRef}
          style={{ display: 'none' }}
          type="file"
        />

    const onChangeHandler = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if (!event.target.files?.length) {
        return;
      }
  
      const formData = new FormData();  
      Array.from(event.target.files).forEach((file) => {
        formData.append(event.target.name, file);
      });
  
      props.onChange(formData);
  
      formRef.current?.reset();
    };
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the code at `D:\Projects\Node\pdf2pic\controllers\convert.js:9:44`? You are probably trying to access the `req.files` array there, but with using `single` there is no array, but just a `req.file` property. (Mind the difference `files` vs `file`)

Answer (score 2):

Main difference between handling single vs multiple file uploads with multer is where the files are located:

- `upload.single()` -> `req.file`
- `upload.array()` (and `upload.fields()`) -> `req.files`

You can't swap from multiple to single without also accounting for this change further down in your code.

Judging from your error message, in `convert.js` file (at line 9 column 44) you're failing to read the first element of an array `req.files`. That's because `req.files` doesn't exist and you should work with `req.file` instead which is an object.

This free guide for [Parsing Requests in Node.js](https://maximorlov.com/request-parsing-nodejs-guide/) will help you fix these types of errors when working with file uploads in Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

use both  like a middleware in router

const uploadFiles = multer({'./images}).single("profile");
const uploadtext = multer().array()